# CodedUI Tests suddenly throwing exceptions in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I have a whole bunch of Unit tests and coded UI Tests setup in my project, all running only on my local box (although they are all in TFS).

Everything was working fine until I added a new CodedUI Test - suddenly none of my Coded UI Tests will work, they are all throwing the same exception:

[image: Exception screenshot]

Can anybody help?

### Edit

Okay, have discovered that adding `Playback.Initialize();` in my `TestMethod` allows it to run.

So why has the built in engine stopped calling this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio or Resharper added the TestClass() attribute to my CodedUI test class, which is what broke the whole thing.

Removing that attribute from the class fixed the problem.